# Return a value from json data if two values are equal

Tags: jquery, json

```
function getusername(userid) {
  $.get('/getRecentSignups', function (data) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(data);

//prints
{"_id":"5306e7fd80b1027ad2653db4","email":"priya@gmial.com","id":"27","password":"priya","signedtime":"2014-02-21 11:15:33"},{"_id":"5306e81880b1027ad2653db5","email":"anju@gmail.com","id":"35","password":"anju","signedtime":"2014-02-21 11:16:00"}]

// userid passing here is 35

    data = data.filter(function(val) {
       return (val.id === userid)
         });
  });
}
```

In the above function `getusername()` I am passing `userid 35`

Data prints  //prints

```
    {
  "_id": "5306e7fd80b1027ad2653db4",
  "email": "priya@gmial.com",
  "id": "27",
  "password": "priya",
  "signedtime": "2014-02-21 11:15:33"
},
{
  "_id": "5306e81880b1027ad2653db5",
  "email": "anju@gmail.com",
  "id": "35",
  "password": "anju",
  "signedtime": "2014-02-21 11:16:00"
}]
```

I have to return corresponding email   when `userid` equals `data.id` how it is possible?

Comment: well, password is being received as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't return a value from the method as it is asynchronous, you need to use a callback pattern to solve this like

```
function getusername(userid, callback) {
    $.get('/getRecentSignups', function (data) {
        data = data.filter(function (val) {
            return (val.id == userid)
        });
        if (data && data.length) {
            callback(data[0].email);
        } else {
            callback(userid);
        }
    });
}
getusername(35, function (email) {
    //do something
})
```

See [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @Sush share how you have used the method `getusername`

Comment: one thing also am doing when userid="guest" i have to return callback(userid) and if userid="35" i have to return callback(data[0].emai;)

Comment: `function getusername(userid, callback) {
    $.get('/getRecentSignups', function (data) {     
        if (data.id === userid) {
            callback(data[0].email);
        }
    else
    {   
      callback(userid);  
    }
    });
}`and that call back eoor is not getting now

Comment: @Sush but you removed the filter logic why is that

Comment: @Sush your initial logic and the one posted above does not match

Comment: i think while using that filter it doent returns data when userid="guest" dats y i remove that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48047/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-sush)